# How to Upload file to mysql using url(remote uploading) in php

Tags: php, mysql

My query is that , I want to upload big size videos from URL to my MySQL(To MySQL because I do not want to share direct download links to user)
I want a code which Upload from URL Store to MySQL And create temporary Download links which are deleted after some time...

(please explain in detail,)

Comment: Please show the effort that you've put in to it. Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: So you want code to: Upload a video to a website, Store it in MySQL database, Create temp download link, then expire the download link? This is a very big job, and SO is not a coding service. We can answer small specific programming problems, we will not "explain" in detail like this. Break it down into steps, then start coding, and Good Luck!!

Comment: You should also ask yourself the question if MySQL is the right database to store large video files in? Interesting discussion at http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database